# Angular [Material] - Injetar componentes dinâmicamente em um template

Tags: angular

Tenho dois elementos estáticos no projeto, que nunca vão sumir, somente o conteúdo, esses são o menu do topo e uma sidenav, apartir da rota quero inserir componentes dentro do `<mat-sidenav-content></mat-sidenav-content>` conforme vou navegando, a principío é simples, mas é de outro componente, então seria inserir componentes dentro do template.

```html
   <!-- sidenav.component.html -->

<mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav mode="side" opened>
    <a>teste</a>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <!-- componentes aqui -->
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>


<!-- top-menu.component.html -->

<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <p>works</p>
</mat-toolbar>

<!-- index.component.html -->
<app-top-menu></app-top-menu>
<app-sidenav></app-sidenav>

<p>index component</p>
```

No app.component.html só tenho `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`, então a ideia é que toda vez que um usuário acessar o app, caia no login e depois carregue essa sidenav e qualquer outro component dentro do `mat-sidenav-content`

Teoricamente eu faria isso em um component, adicionaria os templates e o conteúdo iria no local correto, porem, ele fica abaixo do sidenav:

Segue imagens: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Component index inserido abaixo do template:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como deveria ser:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que o `<mat-sidenav>` funcione corretamente é necessário projetar todo o conteúdo do app **dentro** da tag `<mat-sidenav-content>`.
Para colocar um componente dentro do outro utilize a tag `<ng-content>`. Ela funciona como um *slot* para que você possa inserir tags/conteúdo dentro do seu componente angular.

```
<!-- sidenav.component.html -->
<mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav mode="side" opened>
    <a>teste</a>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <!-- componentes aqui -->
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Com isso, agora é possível colocar o componente `<app-top-menu>` **dentro** do componente `<app-sidenav>`:

```
<!-- index.component.html -->
<app-top-menu>
  <app-sidenav></app-sidenav>
</app-top-menu>
```

---

Referências:

- https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview
- https://medium.com/claritydesignsystem/ng-content-the-hidden-docs-96a29d70d11b

Comment: Com alguns ajustes, isso é realmente o que eu queria, o que eu mudei é que <app-top-menu> fica isolado acima e o ng-content vai dentro do content da sidenav, com isso, o conteúdo eu coloco dentro da tag da sidenav e funciona perfeitamente, obrigado, você me ajudou a finalizar =D